# Is it possible to see an image with radio telescope of something not so far away in detail?

Tags: telescope, photography, radio-telescope, post-processing

Can an image of a person using a radio telescope see a person from far away? Could a radio telescope be made to see someone walking on Mars?

https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30477/could-we-see-someone-walking-on-mars-from-earth

Comment: How close is it to the guy? Can we put a camera 10 ft away from him and capture the data then relay it to an intermediate satellite? I think you need to revise your question a bit. You use a lot of terms and don't explain them fully in terms of the true question you're asking. Is this telescope on earth?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn revised

Comment: Once again where is the observer-- I assume on earth? In orbit around earth? Orbit around mars? 10 ft from his face?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn let us say Earth.

Comment: I think the main problem here is "Will the person be emitting significant amounts of radio waves"?

Comment: Could radio waves be made linear then pinged off the person to create an image like a flash light radio strobe for long distant x-ray picture surface picture.

Comment: You aren't going to get much detail looking at a human with radio waves. We're rather transparent at that frequency, and the wavelength's way too big. Calculate the wavelegth of a 100 MHz FM radio wave. You'd have more luck with microwaves, aka radar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In brief: you cannot resolve details of an object on a scale less than roughly a wavelength or two.  The distance to the object only marginally affects this problem.

So take a look at the wavelengths your radiotelescope is capable of receiving and compare with dimensions of interesting "features" on a human body.

Further, as the comments pointed out, unless the human is either emitting radio-wavelength energy in significant amounts (unlikely) or is being "painted" by a large emitting source (as active radar systems do), you won't get any signal in the first place.